# Make Media player time line using Slider

Tags: wpf, slider

I'm using a `Slider` for showing media time line.while media is playing i update sidebar value with this lines of code:

```
 void SoundTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SliderBar.Value = GetCurrentTimePosation();
  }
```

but with this  `SliderBar.ValueChanged` event every time called and i cant change time line position with mouse:(when i change it it return to `GetCurrentTimePosation()` time)

```
  void SeekToMediaPosition(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
           media.setpos((uint)e.NewValue);
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got The answer:according [seek-bar-for-media-element-in-wpf](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/seek-bar-for-media-element-in-wpf/),I must add two event to `Slider`

```
Thumb.DragStarted="sliderTime_DragStarted"
Thumb.DragCompleted="sliderTime_DragCompleted"
```

and while dragging disable my timer.

complete Answer : [seek-bar-for-media-element-in-wpf](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/seek-bar-for-media-element-in-wpf/)